# Div not closing correctly with Jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user highlights text a DIV will pop-up, but if the user when clicks anywhere on the page it automatically goes away which I don't want. Also, i'm having trouble getting the div to close and then re-open when I want to highlight a different range of text. If I highlight one range of text and then go to highlight another range or text, the div that opens that first time will close and not re-open.

Any help would be great!
Liveweave below:

http://liveweave.com/WBf1h4

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class=" text">
    <p>Having been in the field, most recently in India, I have seen that access to safe water is just a few dollars away for many people. A small loan can create a pathway to a household water tap. Making access to capital ubiquitous and affordable for those living in poverty would go a long way towards eliminating water stress.</p>

    <p>Due to a combination of problems, including rapid population growth, constrained water supplies and high levels of poverty, countries such as India, Indonesia, Bangladesh and Nigeria will be hit the hardest by this trend. Resource-constrained water stress will be the norm for many countries in Asia, while finance-constrained water stress will be the norm for many countries in Africa. This is reflected in the fact that experts surveyed by the World Economic Forum expect Sub-Saharan Africa to be the most affected region, closely followed by Asia.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown" id="txtmen" style="display:none;">
    <div class="sendform">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="contact" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="Contact" maxlength="30">
      </div>
      </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="message" class="form-control" 
          placeholder="Message" maxlength="40" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Send</button>
        </div>
</form>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

jquery:

```
function getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.getSelection) {
        return document.getSelection();
    }
    else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
        if (selection.text) {
            return selection.text;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

//if browser is mozilla
//add IE compatability too
var selection= getSelected();//sets selected text to var selection
function checkObj(){
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0); //gets a range of the characters selected 
    var newNode = document.createElement('span');//maybe a span or div, try both
    newNode.setAttribute("class", "selectedText");
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
    var dropbutton= document.getElementById('txtmen');
    if(newNode.innerHTML.length > 0) {
        newNode.appendChild(dropbutton);
        }  
    if (window.getSelection) {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
        else if (document.selection){ 
        document.selection.empty();
        }
}

function exitDropdown(){
   $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if(event.which === 27) {
            $('.dropdown').toggle('hide');
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
});
}

function showDropdown(){
   $('.dropdown').toggle('show', function(e){
    document.getElementById('contact').focus();
  });
}

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    checkObj();
    showDropdown();
    exitDropdown();
});
```

Comment: Binding an event handler inside another event handler is almost always wrong. You should just call `exitDropdown` once, not every mouseup.

Comment: The code appears to have multiple problems and not work as described.

Comment: I don't understand what `showDropdown` is doing. `.focus()` doesn't return a value, why are you using it as the boolean for toggling?

Comment: @barmar sorry had pasted the wrong liveweave URL in the question, I updated it with the right one, don't mind the CSS, i'm still working on that. the autofocus in the HTML code isn't being used, I removed it. It's being called in the javascript with .focus()....showDropdown is called to acutally show the menu. Use the updated liveweave to check it out.

Comment: I'm just looking at the code in the question, not liveweave.